# select distinct statement not working doesnt display unique values instead shows all

Tags: mysql, sql

From these data: [image]

```
  SELECT DISTINCT bank_trans.NAME, bank_trans.ID, bank_trans.BVN 
    FROM bank_trans 
    WHERE bank_trans.BVN NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT taxpayers.bvn 
                                 FROM taxpayers)
```

The query above should display just 3(unique) users but it displays all 14 records,
thanks.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT bank_trans.BVN) AS "full_count" 
FROM bank_trans 
WHERE bank_trans.BVN NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT taxpayers.bvn 
                             FROM taxpayers)
```

the above code works for count displays 3

Comment: Distinct is over all the selected columns not just the first one..

Comment: It seems your data has 14 unique rows, with only 3 unique `bank_trans.BVN`.

Comment: @P.Salmon so what should i do now. the count code works fine but the first code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @Luuk yes 3 unique bvn and 14 unique records

Comment: @Bashton difficult to share that it private data, but the general idea is that 14 unique rows that has 3 unique BVN, and i only want to get just the 3 tax payers with the 3 unique BVN

Comment: Try `SELECT DISTINCT BVN FROM bank_trans`. Because if multiple records for a BVN exists, it is currently unknown which other data to return.

Comment: @Luuk thanks for your response, this doesn't work or maybe can you try sending the full query maybe i am doing it wrongly

Comment: @Luuk okay let me work on that thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for `GROUP BY`, I believe.

```sql
SELECT bank_trans.BVN, bank_trans.NAME,
       COUNT(*) number_of_transactions_from_unknown_taxpayers
  FROM bank_trans 
 WHERE bank_trans.BVN NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT taxpayers.bvn 
                                 FROM taxpayers)
 GROUP BY  bank_trans.BVN, bank_trans.NAME
```

By the way, SELECT DISTINCT is the same as

```sql
SELECT col1, col2, col3
  FROM tbl
 GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
```

It works on all the columns mentioned in the SELECT DISTINCT, not just the first one.

Comment: thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The BVN is probably the Nigerian Bank Verification Number. Every customer is identified by this unique ID.

You select from a transaction table. It s natural that we can find a BVN in there multiple times. The name would usually always be the same for one BVN, unless it changes by marrigae, say from Mary Smith to Mary Miller.

As you want each customer only once in your results, the transaction ID makes no sense. Don't select it. Your query would thus become:

```
SELECT DISTINCT bank_trans.name, bank_trans.bvn
FROM bank_trans 
WHERE bank_trans.bvn NOT IN (SELECT taxpayers.bvn FROM taxpayers)
ORDER BY bank_trans.bvn;
```

This would get rid of almost all duplicates for a BVN. Only Mary would appear twice, once as Mary Smith, once as Mary Miller. And this may even be desired. If it is not, then decide for one. If it doesn't matter whether to pick the older name or the newer one, then:

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(bank_trans.name) AS customer_name, bank_trans.bvn
FROM bank_trans 
WHERE bank_trans.bvn NOT IN (SELECT taxpayers.bvn FROM taxpayers)
GROUP BY bank_trans.bvn
ORDER BY bank_trans.bvn;
```

If you want to pick the last used name, then you need a subquery for the ordering. For instance with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT name, bvn
FROM
(
  SELECT
    name, bvn,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY bvn ORDER BY transaction_date DESC) AS rn
  FROM bank_trans
  WHERE bvn NOT IN (SELECT taxpayers.bvn FROM taxpayers)
)
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY bvn;
```

(This last query also gives you the option to select more data from the last transaction, e.g. the last transaction ID.)

Comment: thanks removing ID worked.